# Shiro returning wrong user data

Tags: database, jboss7.x, vaadin, shiro, objectdb

we have problem with shiro returning results from another logged user. Our setup is JBOSS AS 7.1.1., Apache Shiro 1.2.1, Vaadin 7.1.6 and ObjectDB 2.4.6.

Thing is that when we have multiple users logged in to the application users get data within grids/tabels from another logged user. Also when we use subject.getPrincipal Shiro returns user name from another logged user.

Plase if anybody can help  on this.

Kind regards.

Comment: Might be that you have push activated? The look here http://mikepilone.blogspot.ch/2013/07/vaadin-shiro-and-push.html

Comment: Yes, that may be it.Thanks for a great tip. Regards

Comment: Hi we tried with diasabling the push,but it didnt resolve the issue altough we resolved some other issues.

Comment: It seems we forgot to add ShiroFilter in our web.xml. Here is the link of our other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706567/mixing-user-session-data-in-jboss)

Comment: I've got ShiroFilter defined in my web.xml but I'm seeing the same issue.  Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Hi Shadowman! Do you have static fields/methods in your application? Maybe table declared as static or something similar?