# mixing user session data in jboss

Tags: session, jboss, vaadin, mixing

if someone can help with JBoss returning data from wrong user. Our setup is JBOSS 7.1.1 with Vaadin 7.1.6 and Shiro.

Our current problem is when multiple users use our Vaadin application it frequently returning data from other users to another curently loged user,. ie it is mixing users data. We have tried reinstaling the PC, changing browsers, disabling caching..., nothing helped. We aded CDI UI addon from Vaadin but it doesnt help.

Our previous issue with similar problem 
[Shiro returning wrong user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548855/shiro-returning-wrong-user-data)

We resolved some other authentication problems with disabling push but this problem stil persist.

Any help apreciated

Comment: Looks like you mix up scopes. Please show some code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response! It seems that we needed to add ShiroFilter in our web.xml. When we added it, everything is working fine (at least for the last three days).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but when i got to this page my web.xml was already setup.
I´m using JBoss AS 7.1.1, JSF 2 and Shiro. A user receive data from another sessionScope ManagedBean after an ajax call.
Any help apreciated.

Comment: Do you have static fields/methods in your application?

Answer (score 0):

If enyone else has the same issue, this is what you need to add to your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

...

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```